# How to change index of the multidimentional array below?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How to change this bellow array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 35.2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 49.5
            )            

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 44
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 38.5
            )

    )
)
```

into

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 35.2             

        [1] =>49.5                            

    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  44                

        [1] => 38.5                

    )

)
```

Comment: I have recursion function which will give you all values in single array... is it fine for you ?

Answer (score 2):

The easy, easy way is a simple nested foreach:

```
// be sure to include the &. Otherwise your edits will do nothing.
foreach( $input as &$level1 )
{
    // level 1 is the array of the arrays which contain your values
    // we need the keys and the arrays which hold the desired values
    foreach( $level1 as $key => $level2 )
    {
       // assign the key to be the value at 0 instead of its current value
       // (which happens to be level2)
       $level1[ $key ] = $level2[ 0 ];
    }
}
```

Sheepy proposed use of array_merge with call_user_func_array below. That is a good idea and I gave it a +1. (I encourage others to do the same). To see which was better, I decided to run a benchmark on both solutions:

The results:

```
 manual              0.074267864227295
 call_usr_func_array 0.13694596290588
 manual              0.080928087234497
 call_usr_func_array 0.13510608673096
```

I then reversed test order:

```
 call_usr_func_array 0.14956903457642
 manual              0.066309928894043
 call_usr_func_array 0.14821600914001
 manual              0.064701080322266
```

Here's the benchmark code:

```
$st = microtime(1);
$input = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++ )
    $input[] = array( array( 1 ),array(  2 ),array(  3 ) );

// be sure to include the &. Otherwise your edits will do nothing.
foreach( $input as &$level1 )
{
    // level 1 is the array of the arrays which contain your values
    // we need the keys and the arrays which hold the desired values
    foreach( $level1 as $key => $level2 )
    {
       // assign the key to be the value at 0 instead of its current value
       // (which happens to be level2)
       $level1[ $key ] = $level2[ 0 ];
    }
}
print microtime(1) - $st;
print PHP_EOL;
$st = microtime(1);
$input = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++ )
    $input[] = array( array( 1 ),array(  2 ),array(  3 ) );

foreach ( $input as $k => $ary ) {
  $input[$k] = call_user_func_array ( 'array_merge' , $ary );
}
print microtime(1) - $st;
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Isn't `$level1` just a temporary variable that PHP creates for the `foreach` loop?

Comment: My advice is to `unset($level1)` at the end of the main loop. Otherwise, you can learn how tricky references can be.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter version.  It is still a nested loop in reality, though.

```
foreach ( $input as $k => $ary ) {
  $input[$k] = call_user_func_array ( array_merge , $ary );
}
```